# ReactJS Ant Design - Open DatePicker on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, antd

I am using ant design framework for ReactJS, where I am trying to find a solution to open **DatePicker** on button click, however this seems not possible with the framework component, I have tried to use third party DatePicker but it doesn't work well with it.

My requirement is to have a simple input and beside of it there will be a button, on clicking the button DatePicker should popup..

This is my [unfinished demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/jvz1mw5vyy)

If anyone has worked on such solution, please help.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to specify the "open" property on the datepicker (eg: `<Datepicker open={this.state.isDatepickerOpen} />`. Then, we can toggle this state whenever we click the button

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`DatePicker` has an `open` prop that you can set to a `boolean` value. Add an `onClick` event to your button and then you can toggle the state of the datepicker.

> I don't want to show that DatePicker input box, and choosing date to fill value in other Input field, any solution?

Without me detailing the styling part of this problem you can use the `onChange` event to set the value of the other `input`.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        pickerOpen: false,
        selectedDate: null
    }
}

togglePicker = () => {
    this.setState({pickerOpen: !this.state.pickerOpen});
}

handleChange = selectedDate => {
    this.setState({selectedDate});
}

const { pickerOpen, selectedDate } = this.state;
<Input value={selectedDate && moment(selectedDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}/>
<DatePicker open={pickerOpen} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
<Button onClick={this.togglePicker}>
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but I don't want to show that `DatePicker input box`, and choosing date to fill value in other Input field, any solution? Here is my [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jvz1mw5vyy) Thanks.

Comment: @iphonic I've added the `React` part of your solution however you'll have to decide how you want to hide the default `DatePicker` field via `CSS`. May I ask why you want to use your own input field instead of the one they provide?

Comment: Yes as per requirement they want picker as optional, thanks for help I can proceed. Cheers.

Comment: @iphonic could you please share your answer to this... as i am stuck in this requirement as well

Comment: I was able to replace the input with a custom component using this answer. Here is my [solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/ant-date-picker-e2yjo?file=/index.js). What I did was hide the picker and draw a custom component on top of it. This will ensure the popover is drawn correctly.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `open` field in antd Datepicker to toggle the datepicker on button click.

```
<DatePicker
   open={this.state.openDatePicker}
   onOpenChange={this.datePickerStatus}
/>
<Button
   type="primary"
   style={{ marginLeft: "100px" }}
   onClick={this.toggleDatePicker}
>
  <Icon type="calendar" theme="outlined" />
</Button>
```

You can toggle the `open` field using the function `toggleDatePicker` called on button click:

```
toggleDatePicker = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    openDatePicker: !prevState.openDatePicker
  }));
};
```

You might also want to close the date picker on clicking outside, this can be achieved by:

```
hideDatePicker = () => {
  this.setState({
    openDatePicker: false
  });
};

datePickerStatus = status => {
  if (!status) {
    this.hideDatePicker();
  }
};
```

You can find the live example linked [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/k9q7n32o6v)

Comment: Wow yes, but I don't want to show that DatePicker input box, and choosing date to fill value in other Input field, any solution? Thanks.